# JSON Parsing check if value exists in the array

Tags: c#, json

I'm new and just learning parsing with JSON

I'm checking if value exists in the array. my code is worked but I just wanna ask the shortest code or improvement for this?

this is what I'm getting: **m3u8** It's randomely exists from array [0] to [4].
so I tried .contains method.

```
  public static async Task<string> GetInfoAsync(string url)
    {
        var resource = await GetWebSourceAsync(url);
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(resource);

        var m3u8 = string.Empty;

        if (jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][0].Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
        {
            m3u8 = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][0]["m3u8"].Value<string>();
        }
        else if (jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][1].Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
        {
            m3u8 = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][1]["m3u8"].Value<string>();
        }
        else if (jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][2].Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
        {
            m3u8 = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][2]["m3u8"].Value<string>();
        }
        else if (jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][3].Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
        {
            m3u8 = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][3]["m3u8"].Value<string>();
        }
        else if (jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][4].Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
        {
            m3u8 = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"][4]["m3u8"].Value<string>();
        }

        return m3u8;
    }
```

[image: Here's the structures of JSON]

Comment: Does what you are parsing have a regular schema? If so, create a set of C# classes and parse the data into a graph of objects. Walking through a set of strongly typed objects would be faster than what you are doing

Comment: Ahm what do you mean regular schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ to your advantage:

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
var m3u = jObject["data"]["program"]["video"]
    .Where(i => i.Value<string>().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?["m3u8"].Value<string>();
```

Let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: It says: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.'

Comment: Alright I got it. it worked. I'll post the solution

Comment: Yeah. it's also helped me for the subtitle. Because the subtitle are different Language with random object as well :)

Comment: I guess you can improve the code by merging Where and FirstOrDefault by writing predicate of 'Where' into 'FirstOrDefault'. IntelliSense should suggest it for you.

Comment: Oh I see. but the subtitle I talked about is not in the "video" Object
it's from ["data"]["program"]["stl"]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your json text be similar to (it may have much more data, it does not matter):

```
{
    "data": {
        "program": {
            "video": [
                {
                    "m3u8Url": "http://go.to/video1",
                    "vid": "",
                    "rp": 0 
                },
                {
                    "m3u8Url": "http://go.to/video2",
                    "m3u8": "#EXTM3U #EXT-X-TARGET...",
                    "vid": "",
                    "rp": 0
                },
                {
                    "m3u8Url": "http://go.to/video3",
                    "vid": "",
                    "rp": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the first video containing **#EXTM3U** using the following code:

```
var anonymousObj = new
{
    data = new
    {
        program = new
        {
            video = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    m3u8Url = "",
                    m3u8 = "",
                    vid = "",
                    rp = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymousObj);
var video = obj?.data?.program?.video?.FirstOrDefault(v => v.m3u8?.Contains("#EXTM3U") == true);
```

**Other solution**, if you're using visual studio, you can map any JSON text to class using the editor. Go to Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes. The output for example JSON will be:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Program program { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public Video[] video { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public string m3u8Url { get; set; }
    public string vid { get; set; }
    public int rp { get; set; }
    public string m3u8 { get; set; }
    //it will have other props
}
```

Then you can use the JsonConvert and deserialize to Rootobject type.

```
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
var video2 = obj2?.data?.program?.video?.FirstOrDefault(v => v.m3u8?.Contains("#EXTM3U") == true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I'm currently trying it :)

Yes it's the same structure
Like this. only the changes is the position of the value "#EXTM3U" 

https://i.imgur.com/ygkiGsg.jpg

Comment: Its a bit different, `video` is an object... you need to make small changes to make it work.

Comment: To update the answer, please attach an image to see any node with `#EXTM3U` inside.

Comment: Yeah @dbvega it's an object. That's what I'm trying to say 
It's randomely exists from object [0] to [4].
by the way I tried your code so maybe I have to find out how to use it for the object
I got this error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'data

Comment: I just see the image, now I figured out where is `#EXTM3U`... I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @dvega. But your method will be helpful in my next project. I already saved it in my collection

Comment: @zackmark15 nice! Please check the updated answer, if works for you, please accept it as answer.

Comment: Alright wait I'll test it. Can I accept two answers?

Comment: Wow it worked. it's really amazing I can also get and add some information from public class Video

Comment: The only little problem is the result isn't formatted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217660/discussion-between-zackmark15-and-dbvega).

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is the solution by @Volodymyr
Thank you so much.

```
  public static async Task<string> GetInfoAsync(string url, EpisodeInfo info)
    {
        var resource = await GetWebSourceAsync(url);

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(resource);
        return jObject["data"]["program"]["video"]
            .Where(i => i.ToString().Contains("#EXTM3U"))
            .FirstOrDefault()
            ?["m3u8"].ToString();
    }
```

and Here's the solution by @dbvega Thanks too.

```
   public static async Task<string> GetWebSourceAsync(string url)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = null,
            UseProxy = false
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "GET");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
                var result = obj?.data?.program?.video?.FirstOrDefault(v => v.m3u8?.Contains("#EXTM3U") == true);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            }
        }
    }
```